# My app requires 256 MB of RAM. I need to set up this value in plist.(for app store distribution). How can I do this?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

My app requires 256 MB of RAM. I need to set up this value in plist.(for app store distribution).

frankly speaking, my app assumed 130МВ . I need to support 3gs, 4g, ipad , and ipod touch with 256 mb. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, that's a lot of memory and maybe a better strategy would be to work with less -- there is no guarantee that your app will work fine on a 3GS with iOS 5 for example.

But to directly answer the question: there is no way to directly require a device with a specific amount of memory, but there are a few flags that should mostly do the trick.

For example, you could require `arm7` or `opengles-2` in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` property of your Info.plist. I *think* that would limit you to 3GS and above.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Your app won't get 256MB of RAM, it will get killed once you start using between 20 -> 30MB. You will receive memory warnings early on and if you choose not to respond by freeing memory, your appplication is at risk of immediate termination.

EDIT:

From what you are describing, you probably want to look at image tiling techniques.

Comment: frankly speaking, my app assumed 130МВ

Comment: YOU don't get all the memory - the operating system needs most of it.

Comment: @Voloda2: Are you sure that you don't mix up physical and virtual memory? Because the iOS is very generous in granting large amounts of virtual memory but will kill your App after a lot less physical memory usage

Answer (score 0):

1. iPhone 1: 128MB
2. iPhone 3G: 128MB
3. iPhone 3GS: 256MB
4. iPhone 4: 512MB

Guess 256MB is a "little" too big for an iPhone app...

Comment: frankly speaking, my app assumed 130МВ

Comment: That's still way too much... You should keep it around 20MB... What are you doing in your app so it requires so much memory?!?

Comment: there is a map with a lot of pictures , you can zoom in / zoom out it; on 3gs my app works perfectly

Comment: We need to redesign. It's very expensive. I need the same requirement as on the photo.

Comment: Use image tiling in that case, you won't need anything like 130MB.

Comment: @Voloda2: Session 104 - Designing apps with scrollviews from the 2010 WWDC is your friend. Go ahead, watch it and then redesign your app! The exact same example (photos app) is used in the talk. Oh and by the way, when you attend this year, visit the scrollview talk again. Its awesome!

Comment: @JustSid  There is 50 objects on my map. They may be different colours. For example : country flag. It may belong any country. I cann't use scrollview suite because my objects is dynamics. User can change flag on map in real time.

Comment: @Voloda2: No, don't use something existing. Please watch the talk and see what options you have to increase your performance and how to lower your memory footprint.